# How do I quit in standalone or in editor mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 5.4.1f1 Personal on windows 10 64bit

I will explain all the steps i did and all the things i tried so far.

Firs time i created a new c# file with the original code:
Now when i press the Escape key it will go back to the editor but will not QUIT the game ! You can't stop the editor play button and quit the game when using [InitializeOnLoad]. To quit the game you can only do it with Build And Run in Standalone mode then you can make Application.Quit();

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class FullscreenPlayMode : MonoBehaviour {

    //The size of the toolbar above the game view, excluding the OS border.
    private static int tabHeight = 22;

    static FullscreenPlayMode()
    {
        EditorApplication.playmodeStateChanged -= CheckPlayModeState;
        EditorApplication.playmodeStateChanged += CheckPlayModeState;

        EditorApplication.update += Update;

    }

    static void CheckPlayModeState()
    {
        if (EditorApplication.isPlaying)
        {
            FullScreenGameWindow();
        }
        else 
        {
            CloseGameWindow();
        }
    }

    static EditorWindow GetMainGameView(){
        EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Window/Game");

        System.Type T = System.Type.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView,UnityEditor");
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo GetMainGameView = T.GetMethod("GetMainGameView",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
        System.Object Res = GetMainGameView.Invoke(null,null);
        return (EditorWindow)Res;
    }

    static void FullScreenGameWindow(){

        EditorWindow gameView = GetMainGameView();

        Rect newPos = new Rect(0, 0 - tabHeight, Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height + tabHeight);

        gameView.position = newPos;
        gameView.minSize = new Vector2(Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height + tabHeight);
        gameView.maxSize = gameView.minSize;
        gameView.position = newPos; 

    }

    static void CloseGameWindow(){
        EditorWindow gameView = GetMainGameView();
        gameView.Close();
    }

    static void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Escape)) 
        {
            CloseGameWindow ();
        }
    }
}
```

Then since this is not working as i wanted i tried something else.
I deleted the line: [InitializeOnLoad] but didn't change anything else in the rest of the script.

This time after deleting the line [InitializeOnLoad] i dragged the script into the ThirdPersonController.

Now if i will start the game as before form the editor and hit press the escape key it will back to the editor but will not quit the game !

But now if i make in the menu File > Build & Run i will get two errors:

[image: Errors]

The first error is:

Assets/MyScripts/FullScreenPlayMode.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The second error:

Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

So i went to this solution what suppose to be a solution in this link:

[Not working solution](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/576746/build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-unityeditor.html)

If i move the file script to the EDITOR directory then i can't drag the script to the ThirdPersonController it will throw a message say the script is editor script.

If i tried the second solution in the link:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
     // Editor specific code here
 #endif
```

So i did it in the script in the top:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```

And the script file is not in the Editor directory !
This time when i make Build & Run i'm getting a new another error:

Assets/MyScripts/FullScreenPlayMode.cs(34,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `EditorWindow' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Could not find what is this error with the EditorWindow. This error happen when i used the #if and #endif

So in all the ways i tried so far i got another problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be simplifying your problem but you could simply do this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (EditorApplication.isPlaying)
        {
            EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
        }

#else 
        Application.Quit();
#endif
        }
```