# Cannot finish the game in Unity using Application.Quit()

Tags: unity-game-engine

### I'm making games in Unity.

```
public void OnClickExit()
{
    Application.Quit();

}
```

---

I wrote the code like this.
But, Although when I click the quit button, It doesn't work.
I tried it by using <kbd>Esc</kbd>, too. But it works, neither.
Please give me some answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I quit in standalone or in editor mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39669655/1092820)

Answer (score 17):

`Application.Quit();` will not do anything while playing in the Unity Editor.  But it will work **in a build**.

To improve this experience I use a function like this which will also kick the editor out of play mode so it simulates or feels like a quit.

```
public void Quit() {
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE
        Application.Quit();
    #endif
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks KillerFirefly this worked a treat for me!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see the button is responding to clicks?

Best way is to add a `Debug.Log("Quitting");` to see if it logs in the console.

Buttons are a bit of a faff in Unity, as per the documentation, it's better to create an empty game object, attach the script in the there and declare a button with:

```
`public Button myButton`
```

then drag the button in. More info below:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are running the game in Play Mode?

[This link](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-quit-the-game-in-unity/) states:

> You can quit a game in Unity by calling the Application.Quit function,
> which will close a running application. However, while this works to
> end a built application, Application Quit is ignored when running the
> game in Play Mode in the editor.

R